# Commutative Ring Where Each Element is its own Inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need help with the following problem:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Show that if $1+1=0$ in $R$, then $a+a=0$ for every element $a$ in $R.$

I am not really sure where to begin, so any direction or help is appreciated! Please and thank you.

Comment: Note that this sort of ring has characteristic $2$. You can read more about these sort of rings by looking up rings of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $a+a = a \cdot 1 + a \cdot 1 = a\cdot(1+1)$.